# Why doesn't this React code mutate the state, but vanilla code does?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mutation

Sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/207ml94zj0

The offending bit of code:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log("state before", this.state);
    let a = this.state.tranches.slice(); //Clone the state
    a[0].start = e.target.value;
    a[0].end = 5;
    console.log("state after", this.state);
    this.setState({ tranches: a });
  }
```

If I just reproduce this as some pure javascript:

```js
const state = {
  tranches: [{
    start: "foo",
    end: 1
  }]
}

const value = "bar";

console.log("state before", state);
let a = state.tranches.slice(); //Clone the state
a[0].start = value;
a[0].end = 5;
console.log("state after", state);
```

We can see that the value of `state` is mutated between `state before` and `state after`.

Yet in the sandbox example - that isn't the case.

And actually, what's happening is what's being printed to the console in the React example, is the value of the state *after* the code has run.

Why is that the case?

Comment: Check your browser console. The stack snippet console deep examines the object *immediately*, and logs all of its properties, but the browser console only saves a reference to the object, which, if expanded, will show its *new* value, not the old value (it doesn't save a deep clone of the object to display). It's pretty counter-intuitive. Try using `JSON.stringify` instead in the codesandbox link

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Fantastic, thanks.